# How can I display the current time & date setting?

Tags: time, date

How can I display the current time configuration, like the time zone, in Ubuntu?

Comment: What does the CentOS output for `cat /etc/sysconfig/clock` look like ?

Comment: like this [root@SUPA9611 ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/clock
ZONE="Europe/Amsterdam"
UTC=true
ARC=false

Answer (score 180, accepted):

I don't know of a single file, but this may give you the info needed:

```
cat /etc/timezone
grep UTC /etc/default/rcS
date
# hardware clock
sudo hwclock --show
```

Comment: I didn't spot the `hwclock` bit at first - but that was actually what I was looking for

Answer (score 125):

Best example (IMHO) using **`timedatectl`** (in command-line/terminal):

```
$ timedatectl
      Local time: Thu 2014-07-24 19:51:23 IST
  Universal time: Thu 2014-07-24 14:21:23 UTC
        Timezone: Asia/Kolkata (IST, +0530)
     NTP enabled: no
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: n/a
```

Visit the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/timedatectl) for more settings and further information.

Comment: If your system is missing `timedatectl`: http://askubuntu.com/q/622721/132098

Comment: Additional info that may also be useful: to change time zone do "sudo timedatectl set-timezone America/Los_Angeles" (use your own time zone instead of America/Los_Angeles. Timezones can be found with timedatectl list-timezones)

Answer (score 33):

For me, `date` works:

`Fri 22 Nov 2019 04:31:50 PM UTC`

Answer (score 10):

Check out `info date`, and for example `date +'%z'`

Comment: did not work! the output is like man date

Answer (score 2):

For the time zone, you can use geolocation:

```
$ curl https://ipapi.co/timezone
America/Chicago
```

Or:

```
$ curl http://ip-api.com/line?fields=timezone
America/Chicago
```

http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/time#Time_zone

Answer (score 1):

If you need a formatted area and time zone, you can use:

```
$ grep `date +%Z` /etc/timezone 
  Etc/UTC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) installed:

```
PS> Get-TimeZone

Id                         : Europe/Vilnius
DisplayName                : (UTC+02:00) Eastern European Standard Time
StandardName               : Eastern European Standard Time
DaylightName               : Eastern European Summer Time
BaseUtcOffset              : 02:00:00
SupportsDaylightSavingTime : True
```

I suspect this won't be popular answer in a Linux community, but I really like the verb-noun convention. It makes it easier for me to remember commands, and it will also work on all distributions with PowerShell installed :)

*[Documentation for the `Get-TimeZone` cmdlet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-timezone?view=powershell-6)*