# `timedatectl` without `systemd`

Tags: 12.04, timezone

I want to be able to set timezone for Ubuntu hosts, from command line (given in POSIX format). 
I was searching for options, and found `timedatectl` from `systemd` package but since I did not want the entire `systemd`, but just `timedatectl`, I downloaded the `.deb` package and extracted the `timedatectl` binary, but that expects `GLIBC>=2.17`, I have `GLIBC 2.15` on my Ubuntu `12.04` !

Is there any other utility, which is simple enough to use, that I can install, to set timezone in POSIX format (e.g. `EST+10`)

Comment: I'm on 14.04 , and I use timedatectl without systemd. In 14.04 the init system is still upstart so  . . . Seems like you can use it without systemd.

Comment: @Serg most of the systemd stack can be used without systemd as init, but upgrading glibc is a different game.

Comment: Is EST+10 = EFT?

Answer (score 6):

That would not work:

```
$ sudo timedatectl set-timezone EST+10
Failed to set time zone: Invalid time zone 'EST+10'
```

You'd have to use:

```
$ sudo timedatectl set-timezone EST
```

In Ubuntu 12.04 you can use this command:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/EST /etc/localtime
```

To get `EST` from `EST+10`:

```
grep -Po "^[A-Z]{3,3}"
```

---

**EST+10**

EST is GMT-5, EST+10 is GMT+5

Therefore you can use:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/GMT+5 /etc/localtime
```

Comment: I'd assumed EST+10 meant 10 hours ahead of EST (since EST itself is UTC-5, the 10 couldn't be related to what EST is)

Comment: @muru, yes that is what I found, from an example.

Comment: @A.B, so even with `timedatectl` I cannot use the timezone strings, which are possible with `tzset()` ?

Comment: Timezone is not Offset. See my answer.